# How to add additional field when indexing an object

Tags: nest

So someone defined a class

```
public class TestJobResult
{
    public long StartTimeInUtc_Ticks { get; set; }
}
```

I want to post to ElasticSearch using Nest. The property is in ticks, I want to convert it to DateTime when posting. What's the best way? Is there any way I could add additional properties before calling Index()?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to to this would be to have a seperate c# object that represents the object as you want it to look like in Elasticsearch and do the conversion yourself in code.

You could go nuts here with `JsonConverter`'s but in your case it would only overcomplicate matters.